# The set of convegence of sequences of measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions then the set of points $x$ at which $f_n(x)$ converges to a finite limit is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define, $$\mathcal{A}:= \{ x : \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \hspace{1mm} exists \}$$

and let us define, $$ \mathcal{O}_{n,m}^k := \{ x : |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \le \frac1k \}$$

Notice, that each $\mathcal{O}_{n,m}^k$ is a measurable set as it is the inverse image of the measurable function, $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|$. Furthermore, since $f_n(x)$ converges it must be Cauchy, explaining why I chose such a definition for the above set.

I claim that, $$\mathcal{A} = \bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=N+1} \bigcap_{m=N+1} \mathcal{O}_{n,m}^k$$